# How to repeat boxes until maximum width/height is reached?

Tags: php, javascript, logic

```
    <style> 
div
{
border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:10px 40px; 
background:#dddddd;
width:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>The property allows to Create Chess Boxes.</div>
```

how to repeat the above div rounded boxes until reach max width specified or according to table width or resolution & go down to next line and until reach max-height of the screen or as specified (time-table time) so that there is no need to scroll both width wise & height wise ? help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your boxes to fill the width of the browser, use `float: left` in your css.  To dynamically add boxes until they fill the page, copy the div using `element.cloneNode(true)`, and continue until the bottom point of the div is below the bottom point of the container.

For example, something like this:  [jsfiddle.net/rUUuW/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/rUUuW/1/)

It's a little easier with jQuery: [jsfiddle.net/rUUuW/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/rUUuW/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can't - PHP as a server side component has no notion of browser dimensions.  You need to handle something like this client-side using JavaScript.